# Retrieve a MethodInfo on an int

Tags: c#, reflection, methodinfo

Is it possible to retrieve the MethodInfo for `*` operator on an Int32?

I've tried this code but without success (it returns null):

```
MethodInfo mi = typeof(System.Int32).GetMethod("op_Multiply");
```

Thanks!

Comment: You could do it with System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt32

Comment: 1024 reputation.  I like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible - no such method exists.

Arithmetic on primitive types (except `Decimal`) is implemented as IL instructions (`mul`, `add`, `div`, etc), not methods.
You can see the complete list of IL opcodes [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes_fields.aspx).

Comment: Indeed not possible. A `decimal` is not a primitive type though. If you (Stringer) wants "proof" of this impossibility, try Reflector: http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/